# How to draw intensity over time for 500 channels in C#?

Tags: c#, graph, visualization

I have a measuring device with 500 channels of data, and as I collect them, I need to check whether something meaningful is being collected in these channels. Hence, I would like to draw a graph of the intensity of values over time for each channel. Something a bit like on spectrographs for example in SDR applications, but in a very simplified version.
[image: SDR example]

At the moment I have such a simple code that draws squares on a graph, and all in all something like this would be enough if I could make it so that these squares are next to each other, without gaps, but also without overlapping.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        private Chart chart;
        private Timer timer;
        private Random random;

        private const int ChannelCount = 500;
        private const int MaxValue = 255;
        private const int SquareSize = 10;
        private const int MaxTimeRange = 10;

        private int currentTime;

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitializeChart();
            InitializeTimer();
        }

        private void InitializeChart()
        {
            chart = new Chart();
            chart.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

            // Set up chart area
            ChartArea chartArea = new ChartArea();
            chartArea.AxisX.Minimum = 0;
            chartArea.AxisX.Maximum = MaxTimeRange;
            chartArea.AxisY.Minimum = 1;
            chartArea.AxisY.Maximum = ChannelCount+1;
            chartArea.BackColor = Color.Black;

            // Add the chart area to the chart
            chart.ChartAreas.Add(chartArea);

            // Set up series
            for (int i = 0; i < ChannelCount; i++)
            {
                Series series = new Series();
                series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Point;
                series.Color = Color.White;
                series.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Square;
                series.MarkerSize = SquareSize;
                series.MarkerStep = 1;

                // Add the series to the chart
                chart.Series.Add(series);
            }

            Controls.Add(chart);
        }

        private void InitializeTimer()
        {
            timer = new Timer();
            timer.Interval = 100; // 1 second
            timer.Tick += Timer_Tick;

            random = new Random();
            currentTime = 0;

            timer.Start();
        }

        private void Timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //// Generate random channel values
            //int[] channelValues = new int[ChannelCount];
            //for (int i = 0; i < ChannelCount; i++)
            //{
            //    channelValues[i] = random.Next(MaxValue + 1);
            //}

            int[] channelValues = new int[ChannelCount];
            for (int i = 0; i < ChannelCount; i++)
            {
                if (i == 3)
                {
                    // Slowly rising value for channel 3
                    channelValues[i] = currentTime * 5;
                    Console.WriteLine(channelValues[i]);
                }
                else
                {
                    channelValues[i] = 0;
                }
            }

            // Update the chart series with new values
            for (int i = 0; i < ChannelCount; i++)
            {
                Series series = chart.Series[i];
                series.Points.AddXY(currentTime, i+1);
                series.Points[series.Points.Count - 1].Color = GetColor(channelValues[i]);
                Console.WriteLine(GetColor(channelValues[i]));
            }

            // Remove old data points outside the time range
            foreach (Series series in chart.Series)
            {
                while (series.Points.Count > 0 && series.Points[0].XValue < currentTime - MaxTimeRange)
                {
                    series.Points.RemoveAt(0);
                }
            }

            // Adjust the x-axis range
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = currentTime - MaxTimeRange;
            chart.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Maximum = currentTime;

            currentTime++;
        }



        private Color GetColor(int value)
        {
            // Map the value to a color gradient
            int red = (int)((value / (double)MaxValue) * 255);
            int green = 255 - red;
            int blue = 0;
            return Color.FromArgb(red, green, blue);
        }

    }
}
```

Here is an example as if there were 10 channels of data and in such a situation I have gaps (in channel 3 artificially generated data appear):
[image: 10 channels]
And here for 500 they already overlap and you can hardly see anything:
[image: 500 channels]

Is there any way to embrace this in a relatively simple and decent way?